# Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer

Tags: java, jax-ws, spring-remoting

I'm changing the whole question now. I'm trying to connect to a SOAP service. On windows it works all right, in the application and on SoapUI. On Linux neither of them work.
The output to the same request on Linux comes:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
  <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer</faultstring>
  </S:Fault>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

On the headers it comes:

```
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Tue, 25 Jun 2013 18:03:46 GMT
#status#    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=utf-8
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Anyone knows why it can work on Windows and not on Linux, since it should be sending the same request.